# Should I use "for" in this case?

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions, omissibility

Which sentence below is correct? Or, are they both wrong?

> a) I hope the sign means for a good news, not a bad one.
>   b) I hope the sign means for a good news, not for a bad one.

Comment: Which statement do you think is correct or wrong and why? If you can include what you have understood(your research/effort in understanding the problem) so far, it will be easier to write an answer. Welcome to ELU!

Comment: Hi @BiscuitBoy , thank you for getting back to me. I am a non-native English speaker and this is my first time to be at ELU. I would prefer the first sentence, as it just sounds natural/familiar to me, but I do not know whether and why it is right (or wrong). I have similar questions on sentences such as "better to be safe than sorry", "better safe than sorry", and "better to be safe than to be sorry". I think the first two are more often to see and presumably correct, but is the last one wrong?

Comment: Neither is correct.

Comment: @Hardevgun Hi, please do not edit any post just for punctuation and style.  It could be rejected in a peer review.

Answer (score 3):

Does this sentence better state what you want to say? "I hope this is a sign of good news, not bad."

Comment: Hi @F. Roberts , thank you for posting back. I realized that I used a poor example in my question, but I could not edit it afterward, since I posted in guest mode. Wish you forgive me on that.    Now the following three sentences would serve my question better:    a) I hope this is for me, not you.  b) I hope this is for me, not for you.  c) I hope this is for me, but not for you.    I am not sure which one(s) is correct.

Comment: Each of these three is grammatically correct., A and B have basically the same meaning.  C seems to be a bit stronger in implying that "I hope this is not for you."

Comment: Glad this helped.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

In reply to your comment you posted:

1. *I hope this is for me, not you.* <-- To me this implies that you are speaking to a friend, and you're hoping that it's for you and not for them. This seems like it would be said with a joking tone.
2. *I hope this is for me, not for you.* <-- This is similar to the first one, however it would be said with a more serious tone.
3. *I hope this is for me, but not for you.* <-- Finally, this one is where you would say it and mean it to whoever you're speaking to.

Comment: @Alex No problem